# manually call cron job action programmatically in shopware

Tags: php, cron, shopware

I'm new in shopware.

I want to call cron job function programmatically is there any way ?

I have tried following for call function using command line but getting too many argument error.

```
php bin/console sw:cron:run ACTION-NAME
php bin/console sw:cron:run NAME -f
```

I need one more help is use shopware function out side of shopware my custom file. is it possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can run the specific cronjob by following command.
For example:

```
php bin/console sw:cron:run Shopware_CronJob_ClearHttpCache
```

But it's only possible since Shopware 5.1.**6**, not as Shopware says since 5.1.5.

Answer (score -1):

In case you need just run cron job for testing, you can run cron from browser:

> http://www.myshop.com/backend/cron

There need to replace `myshop.com` to your domain. In this case all cron jobs will be handled by opening this link.

In case for some reason you need to run cron via console, you can do it this way:

```
php5 path_to_shopware/shopware.php /backend/cron
```

There need to replace `path_to_shopware` to your server path.

Comment: Thank you for answer but this is not useful for me, I think you haven't read carefully my question.

Comment: @Sunny Rathod
Hmm, I'm sorry, maybe I don't understand. Can you describe why it isn't useful for you?

Comment: shopware have multiple cronjobs I want to run one of them not all.  so this is only possible in 5.2.x and I'm using 5.0

Comment: @Sunny Rathod can you describe for what you want to do it? Maybe I can propose different way for performing what you need?

Comment: actually I have my custom cronjob and I would like to run only my cronjob not all but not by schedule, Is there any way to run by using any URL or any file etc...

Comment: @Sunny Rathod I think right way - create component in plugin and you can run method of this plagin as cron job and manually where you need it.
$component = ShopwarePlugins\PluginName\Components\CustomComponent();
$component->doSync();
You can use such code in SubscriberInterface or in your Enlight_Controller_Action..